# To move avd manager from user's profile

Tags: android, environment-variables, android-virtual-device

Hi all,

The avd manager uses the user's profile directory to store AVD files.

But my user profile has a size limitation and I am exceeding this limitation thanks to the simulator images.

The ANDROID_SDK_HOME variable is pointing to C:\Users\myprofile 
so I'm guessing (a newbie here) the problem is here.

Is it posible to change this location so my user's profile size does not have trouble with it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,Don't change the ANDROID_SDK_HOME environment variable,instead
1.goto the %USERPROFILE%.android\avd folder 
2.move the corresponding avd folder to a location(Don't move the .ini file)
3.open the .ini file for your avd and change the value of path to The path where you moved your avd folder to

Comment: Do a wipe before you start your avd